# Let $S_1 , S_2 , S_3 $ be subspaces of $ V(F) $ and $ S_1 \subset S_2$ then prove the following-

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $S_1 , S_2 , S_3 $ be subspaces of $ V(F) $ and $ S_1 \subset S_2$ then prove the following-
$S_1 \cap (S_2 + S_3) = S_2 + (S_1 \cap S_3)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is false. If $S_2=V(F)$ the RHS is $V(F)$. But LHS is contained in $S_1$. Take $S_1=\{0\}$ for a counter-example.